# Batch File: Append a string inside a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following for loop:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
<nul set /p=" %%a - "

Echo !var%%a!
)
```

which will display something like this:

```
1 - REL1206
2 - REL1302
3 - REL1306
```

I need to create a variable that appends itself based on the number of iterations. Example the variable would look like this after the for loop:

```
myVar="1, 2, 3"
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

example:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET /a count=5
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do call set "Myvar=%%Myvar%%, %%a"
ECHO %Myvar:~2%
```

..output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: I wonder where has the first comma gone and what is the point of calling the set operation?

Comment: The first comma and space are skipped by the line `echo %Myvar:~2%` which outputs a substring of %Myvar% starting after the first two characters,

Comment: Finally a working code!!! There's a considerable time since I've started to look for this. Thanks!

Comment: The "call" does the magic. W/o it doesn't accumulate. I searched a while to find this. But what does this, why is this? The "call" doc says "Calls one batch program from another" ...?

Comment: „Batch‟ is magic :-)

Answer (score 10):

Use delayed expansion

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET OUTPUTSTRING=
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
<nul set /p=" %%a - "
Echo !var%%a! 
if .!OUTPUTSTRING!==. (
    SET OUTPUTSTRING=%%a
) ELSE (
    SET OUTPUTSTRING=!OUTPUTSTRING!, %%a
)
)
SET OUTPUTSTRING
```