# Need a loop for computer names on shares

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have this embarrassing .bat:

```
pushd \\computer00081\d    
rmdir "z:\dig_dok" /s /q   
mkdir . "dig_doc"   
cd dig_doc  
xcopy "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\dig_doc" .\ /E  
C:  
net use z: /delete /y
```

The computer names on my network share the same name pattern:
computer00081, computer00082, computer00083... and so on. They have the same file/folder structure in the "d" share.
How can I create a loop for the computer names from let's say computer00001 to computer00200 and do the same for all of them? Maybe do it for a computers.txt list? Or loop them from the hosts file. Thanks in advance! You rock!

Answer (score 1):

While this can be dome in `cmd`, it is much easier in `powershell`. The `for` loop controls the system numbers; from 1 to 9 in this case. Change those to whatever you need. When you are happy with what would be done, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` and `Copy-Item commands.

=== Do-CopyStuff.ps1

```
$DupDir = 'dig_doc'
$SourceDir = Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop') -ChildPath $DupDir
$SHARENAME = 'D'
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 10; $i++) {
    $DestinationDir = '\\COMPUTER' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$SHARENAME"
    if (Test-Path -Path $DestinationDir) {
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $DestinationDir -WhatIf
        Copy-Item -Recurse -Path $SourceDir -Destination $DestinationDir -WhatIf
    }
}
```

If you must run this from `cmd.exe`, this can be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File ".\Do-CopyStuff.ps1"
```

Comment: Yo! Ur s#!t's really lit fam! Exactly what I needed. I did a \$SHARENAME\$DupDir" for the $DestinationDir and made a $PushdDir = '\\COMPUTER' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$SHARENAME" so I can run another "if (Test-Path -Path $PushdDir) { pushd $PushdDir} to pushd the share first otherwise it wont find the network location like that not being mapped. But hey you were a ton of help. You are my personal god now!
/bow

Comment: In PowerShell, pushd is `Push-Location`. But, I do not think you need it. The directory can be referenced by the UNC path. Also, `Push-Location` does not map a drive letter. In `cmd`, you cannot assume that `pushd` maps to Z:. No drive letters are needed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086103/8954127

Looks like string variables are naturally iterable in cmd if there are common delimiters available (like `,`). If you're able to build a comma-delimited string of the computer names, you can loop through them executing on each host.

This answer is incomplete but I think this should spur you in the right direction.

```
set "compnames="

:: needs extra logic to pad missing leading zeros
for /L %%i in (1,1,20) do call set "compnames=%compnames%,computername00%%i"

:: logic to remove any leading comma or space

for %%i in ( %compnames% ) do (
    :: do work with each computer name
    echo %%i
)
```

*A few more references:*

- https://serverfault.com/a/59026
- https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html
- [Batch File: Append a string inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600317/batch-file-append-a-string-inside-a-for-loop/18600971)

Comment: Is there a way to loop through a computers.txt list with all computer names listed there?

Comment: Yes! check out the `FOR /F` doc: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html That can open a file and loop through the lines in a text file